# shelf support removal

Tags: shelving

I want to remove this shelf support in my office. It doesn't move with bare hands at least. I think I need to somehow remove the small round thing that is adjacent to the wall mount. My next action would be using a plier to see if that thing moves. Any advice is appreciated before I break this thing. Thanks!

[image: Shelf Support]

Comment: With most of those, should remove the shelf and then just push up, maybe a tap or two with a hammer.  Should come loose, just little hooks holding them on.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have pretty much exactly the same shelf brackets.

They wedge in place, and the cylinder is NOT the secret to removing them. It stays put on the bracket.

A light tap from a hammer (preferably after removing the shelf) on the bottom next to the wall standard, going upwards, is the way to get them out.

Comment: Looks like the cylinder is just used as a sideways stabilizer, to keep it straight/from flopping sideways.

Comment: Note: you'll probably need to lift it square, to half the height of one of those slots, then it will just come out straight towards you. As soon as you get the first one out, you'll easily see how they key in. Sometimes, if you get unlucky, the next wall screw above can be trapping it a bit.

Comment: Often, a good bang upwards will not only loosen the bracket from its slot but send it flying. Hold the away-from-wall-end gently with one hand while giving it a tap with a hammer in the other hand. Start with light taps, get more energetic as necessary.

Answer (score 2):

**See if its cousins are more tractable.**

I see there are others of this mount type mounted the same way.  See if they come out.  Usually things like this lift vertically and pull forward.  If none of them move then maybe you are right about that peg.  But if this particular one is just jammed or bent somehow, you can figure out from one of the others what it is *supposed* to do, then try to make it do that.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all. The cylinder (or peg, whatever you call it) didn't seem to move. I just kept hitting the bottom part with a hammer toward upside several times and finally it came off. I think it was just too stiff to be done with bare hands. Thanks again for the advices! [image]